# Is it possible to have a separate lib and src directory in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, filesystems, directory-structure

I'm writing a program with a client and a server and I'm trying to organise my source files in an intuative way. I've got this rough file structure:

```
src:  
    client:  
        client.py  
    server:  
        server.py

lib:
    clientlib:
        client_depend.py
    serverlib:
        server_depend.py
    commonlib:
        both_depend.py
```

Previously, I was using the methods which described in [this SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder) but the number of `sys.path.append("../..")`s has gotten out of hand and is in danger of breaking if I move any files about.

What would be a neat and pythonic way to  do this? I've thought about making `lib` a package and putting it in `$(PYTHONDIR)/Lib/site-packages` but that adds complexity to development (as it's a root owned dir and it's not on my USB drive that I use for development so I can change computers easily).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thankyou @Madhuri Patel for correcting the spelling

Comment: @scicyb thank you, is that a file in the same dir that my python file I'm running is in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not making modules that you could import easily when and where you want?

Like this:

```
src:
    __init__.py
    client:
        __init__.py
        client.py
    server:
        __init__.py
        server.py

lib:
    __init__.py
    clientlib:
        __init__.py
        client_depend.py
    serverlib:
        __init__.py
        server_depend.py
    commonlib:
        __init__.py
        both_depend.py
```

Then in `client.py`, you would just have to do:

```py
from lib.commonlib import both_depend
from lib.clientlib import client_depend
```

Comment: Hang on a sec, doesn't seem to be working: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib'`. Do I need to add the `lib` dir to my PATH (or more specifically my sys.path)?

Comment: Well I think you need to add either the `lib` folder or the entire folder of your project to the `sys.path` so that Python would be able to search for the `lib` module.